# How do I set up a camel netty4 component for synchronous request-reply?

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I need to write a camel component that will send a synchronous request-reply over TCP to a legacy system. I have tried to set up a netty4 component, but there is something weird happening. Here is my route:

```
from("direct:foo")
    .doTry()
      .process(exchange -> {
        Message message = (Message) exchange.getIn().getBody();
        logger.info("Sending message: {}", message);
      })
      .toF("netty4:tcp://localhost:%d?sync=true&synchronous=true&requestTimeout=%d&encoders=stubEncoder&decoders=stubEncoder", port, timeout)
        .process(exchange -> {
          Response response = (Response) exchange.getIn().getBody();
          logger.info("[{}] Received reply: {}", exchange, response);
        })
    .endDoTry()
    .doCatch(ReadTimeoutException.class)
      .process(exchange -> {
        // handle timeout...
      })
    .end();
```

The remote port and timeout are injected from properties. The input/output of this route will be domain objects from the rest of the application. I have set up a codec that translates from these domain objects to a simple pipe-delimited string protocol that will be sent to the remote server. I also have a stub program to simulate the legacy host, that listens on a server socket, and sends back a response on the client socket. The stub works fine if I connect to it from a test program.

What I see happening is that the route receives the incoming message, calls the codec to encode the message, and then just waits until it hits the timeout, so then goes into the timeout processor in the catch block. In my stub, I see the connection being made, and then the message is received *after* the timeout. The stub sends the response, but it's too late - the route has already moved on into processing the timeout. I thought that the synchronous=true option would make netty4 send immediately and wait, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Is there some other option that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using .toF and not just .to()..

Comment: The port and timeout values are injected from properties - there are several instances of this route in the real application. There's no real difference between using toF and using to with a manually constructed URI, it's just that toF is easier to read. That's not really relevant to my question, though.

Comment: And you are sure that the process from the codec back to netty works correctly? I have used it previously with the default textline and with String decoder/encoder and that worked. .to("netty4:tcp://localhost:5155?sync=true&synchronous=true&textline=true")

Comment: In debug I can see the codec correctly encoding the message, and then the context is flushed, however the bytes do not appear on the server side until the timeout exception is thrown and the channel is closed by netty. It seems as though there is something preventing the output being written to the socket, but I don't know what.

Comment: I need to use a custom codec, because the actual protocol won't work with textline.

Comment: Hmm..strange one. Only thing that comes to mind is if there is some object not releasing a thread or something and after timeout is forced to.